# How to run ElasticSearch with Titan graph database

Tags: database, graph, titan

I am newbie in Titan, the first thing i do is following the wiki page in Titan github site. 
However, the very first example blocks me.

gremlin> g = GraphOfTheGodsFactory.create('/tmp/titan')

But, it returns:

Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex
Display stack trace? [yN] y
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex

I did not modify any jar files from Titan, and i was using Titian-0.4.4. The elasticsearch jar is 0.90.3, which should be compatible according to their sites. Wish someone could tell me how to do with it.

Also, there are so few code examples in Titan documentation. Is there place i can actually see how to use Java to play with Titan?

Thanks a lot for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Which package did you download? Note that only **Titan/All** and **Titan Server (All + Rexster)** support ElasticSearch.

> Also, there are so few code examples in Titan documentation. Is there place i can actually see how to use Java to play with Titan?

What is your experience with Blueprints in general? If you're totally new to graph databases, start at [GremlinDocs](http://gremlindocs.com/) or [SQL2Gremlin](http://sql2gremlin.com/) if you have some SQL knowledge. Once you have a good understanding of Blueprints, you can dig deeper into Titan specific things like MultiQueries, ElasticSearch index queries, etc. You'll find some really great examples in [Aurelius' Blog](http://thinkaurelius.com/blog/).

Regarding Java: I definitely suggest to start with Groovy in the Gremlin REPL. If you understand the concepts, try it [in Java](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Using-Gremlin-through-Java). But don't start with Java, it would make your experience much worse.

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: Many thanks to you, Daniel. I used Titan/All in current case. I knew basic graph database concepts and also used Neo4j for sometime. But, seems to me, Titan is much harder to get into. I would like to follow your suggestion. Thanks!